# How can i change vue-tweet-embed npm packages, test and use it in my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, vuejs2, vue-component

How can i change [vue-tweet-embed](https://github.com/tonickkozlov/vue-tweet-embed) npm package, test and use it in my project.
i have tried to change it but not able to run or check (as describe in readme file).
i want to make changes for tweet that is not available or deleted then it should handle with some error message or image.

i am getting error like this:

```
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-tweet-embed@1.1.1 prepublish: `npm test && npm run clean && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-tweet-embed@1.1.1 prepublish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-06-29T09_33_32_460Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Fork it and include your forked version.

Comment: @BertEvans i tried but not able to run scripts in readme file.
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.